# CreateFileMappingFromApp UWP (ACCESS DENIED)

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, shared-memory

So I am trying to open a file mapping to communicate with my UWP application via a kernel driver. In a standard non UWP application C++ I can open file mapping perfectly fine, however, UWP requires a few extras to open.

I have added the following to my application manifest includes the following capabilities **codeGeneration** being one of those

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="codeGeneration"/>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
<rescap:Capability Name="allowElevation" />
<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
<uap3:Capability Name="remoteSystem"/>
```

CodeGeneration is needed to call **CreateFileMappingFromApp** this is an alternative from **OpenFileMappingA** as you cannot use **OpenFileMappingA** inside of an UWP application.

The issue is when I try to call CreateFileMappingFromApp with the following parameters

```
CreateFileMappingFromApp(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 5, L"Global\\SharedCommTest");
```

**I get error code 0x5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED** I am completely stuck at this point and any help would be great! :)

I have also enabled SeCreateGlobalPrivilege:

```
ObtainSeCreateGlobalPrivilege()    
{

    HANDLE hToken;
    PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewPrivileges;
    BYTE OldPriv[1024];
    PBYTE pbOldPriv;
    ULONG cbNeeded;
    BOOLEAN fRc;
    LUID LuidPrivilege;

    // Make sure we have access to adjust and to get the old token privileges
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        printf("OpenProcessToken failed with 0xlx\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    cbNeeded = 0;

    // Initialize the privilege adjustment structure
    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME, &LuidPrivilege);

    NewPrivileges = (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)LocalAlloc(
        LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES) + (1 - ANYSIZE_ARRAY) * sizeof(LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES)
    );
    if (NewPrivileges == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    NewPrivileges->PrivilegeCount = 1;
    NewPrivileges->Privileges[0].Luid = LuidPrivilege;
    NewPrivileges->Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    // Enable the privilege
    pbOldPriv = OldPriv;
    fRc = AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        FALSE,
        NewPrivileges,
        1024,
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)pbOldPriv,
        &cbNeeded
    );

    if (!fRc) {

        // If the stack was too small to hold the privileges
        // then allocate off the heap
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {

            pbOldPriv = (PBYTE)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cbNeeded);
            if (pbOldPriv == NULL) {
                return false;
            }

            fRc = AdjustTokenPrivileges(
                hToken,
                FALSE,
                NewPrivileges,
                cbNeeded,
                (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)pbOldPriv,
                &cbNeeded
            );
        }
    }
    return fRc;
}
```

Comment: _"...Creating a file mapping object in the __global__ namespace from a session other than session zero requires the SeCreateGlobalPrivilege privilege. For more information, see Kernel Object Namespaces...."_ see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingfromapp

Comment: I've adjusted this and it still gives me ACCESS_DENIED.

Comment: You didn't check for `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED`, which means "Not all requested privileges were adjusted."